# Is it possible to call AJAX multiple times with updated url data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, for-loop

In JavaScript, I'm trying to

1. Loop through ajax call N number of times
2. This N number is returned AFTER the first ajax call (since the loading_element is displayed when pagination=1)
3. If pages=5 after first ajax call, loop through and call url using pagination=2, pagination=3, pagination=4, pagination=5

**Here's my issue: I'm wondering if it's possible to restart an ajax call or maybe even restart a for loop after getting the updated "pages" value? Thanks so much, any help is appreciated!**

```
    var pages = parseInt(loading_element.attr("data-pages"),10),
    pages_loaded = 0;

    for (var page=1; page<=pages; page++)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:String(document.location).replace("/search/","/search-ajax/"),
            data:"pagination=" + page,
            dataType:$.browser.msie ? "text" : "xml",
            type:"GET",
            success: function(data, url) {
                 // pages element is returned when pagination=1
            }
     }
```

Comment: you can't restart an ajax call, no. Your question isn't fully clear, but I think I get it: If you need to wait for a value to come back from an ajax call before you make the next one, then you can't use a simple for loop, because ajax runs asynchronously. The loop will carry on without waiting for the ajax response. Instead, trigger the next ajax call from the "success" method of the previous one, making use of the updated value received from the server. You could probably make a function to be called recursively which would achieve this.

Comment: I am unclear on what you are asking but it sounds like you need the first ajax call to determine what the value of `pages` is supposed to be? If so, why not make that first ajax request *outside* the loop. Then in it's `success` callback you can trigger the rest of the calls via loop now that you know how many pages there actually are.